Array function at row2 to fill in the entire row is populating it in the same cell for few formulas. How to resolve this issue?
I am creating a function which filter values from the leads generated and updated in the sheets. Formulas are used in  A,E & G using values from other columns already available. It is working for simple formulas with only one column to refer, eg: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"","TRUE"))
Unfortunately creating issues for formulas involving more column references like the one below:
For implementing the following as an array function in A2:
=IF(ISBLANK(B2),"",(if((C2=""), CONCATENATE(B2," Interest ",D2," ",G2),CONCATENATE(B2," Interest"," from ",C2," ",D2," ",G2))))
I tried to use this:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(B2:B),"",(if((C2:C=""), CONCATENATE(B2:B," Interest ",D2:D," ",G2:G),CONCATENATE(B2:B," Interest"," from ",C2:C," ",D2:D," ",G2:G)))))
It is populating all values in all the rows !
I know there's something wrong in what i am trying to do.
I have created a sample file here - Issue reference sheet which has two tabs, one with working function and the other one with errors with arrayformula, which i am trying to resolve with your help.
Support to resolve the same is much appreciated !
Thank you in advance!

Use & instead of CONCATENATE:
=ARRAYFORMULA(
   IF(B2:B="",,
    IF(C2:C="",B2:B&" Interest "&D2:D&" "&G2:G,
      B2:B&" Interest from "&C2:C&" "&D2:D&" "&G2:G)))


That worked ! Thanks a lot @z.. could you please help me understand why concatenate goes wrong here?
Also, in the other cell this function makes a similar issue as explained:
=ARRAYFORMULA( IF(ISBLANK(F2:F),"",if(OR(F2:F="DR-May-24-Leads-LE-Reel",F2:F="DR-May-24-Leads-LE"),"RTH24","RTMA24")))
Could you please help with this too !
Thanks a lot in advance. This was really helpful.

CONCATENATE doesn't work because it's an aggregate function i.e. a function that can take a range as input and return a single value. Same with OR. Use: =ARRAYFORMULA(IF(F2:F="",,IF((F2:F="DR-May-24-Leads-LE-Reel")+(F2:F="DR-May-24-Leads-LE"),"RTH24","RTMA24")))

That helps and the change in the formula works. Thank you so much for your attention and providing a clear solution to the issue @zz..
